# Can electricity be harvested from the soil around plants?

Tags: plant-physiology, photosynthesis, soil

<sup>This is a rehash of a question I originally wrote on [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/30561/18354) which got moved to [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/214295/96479), but I'm really after an answer from a biological perspective.</sup>

A device called the E-Kaia is [making news](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3078365/The-ultimate-power-plant-Biocircuit-harnesses-electricity-soil-houseplant-charge-mobile-phone.html) by claiming to harvest enough electricity from the soil of a pot plant to charge a phone. They claim they can draw 600mA from the soil, which actually wouldn't charge most smartphones in the 1.5 hours they claim in the article (thanks Physics.SE!).

Is there really electricity in the soil around a plant? I can't imagine there being 600mA there for the taking in the soil of a huge tree let alone a pot plant. Maybe it isn't *electricity* in the soil but some other kind of energy or chemical that can be extracted to generate electricity - it *sounds like* the [lemon battery](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/generate-electricity-with-a-lemon-battery/) experiment, which relies on a chemical reaction.

And surely, even if there was electricity there, extracting all of it would damage the plant?

Comment: Actually this is a chemistry question. If you put an anode and a cathode in an electrolyte and a salt bridge, you should get a current. If I remember anything about plant biology (which I really don't) nitrogen fixers should be able to pump Nitrogen to bacteria at their roots that convert it to ammonium, which is a cation and nitrite which is an anion. Add some water and you probably have enough of an electrolyte to generate a current of electrons, though how much and if it is efficient enough to charge anything, I don't know.

Comment: The question in its entirety sounds like off-topic. I suggest that you can break down the question into subquestions which can individually be on-topic in either physics, chemistry or biology. For biology, your question should be on the lines of *whether soil bacteria can create electrochemical potentials of the order of 100mV*. Note that even this is a broad question because this all depends on soil type, temperature, mineral/water content and the microbiota.

Answer (score 2):

Electricity may be indirectly generated from plants through the use of a [microbial fuel cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microbial_fuel_cell), in which biologically-catalyzed chemical reactions are used to drive an electrochemical cell.

A non-technical description of the technology can be found [here](http://www.gizmag.com/plant-microbial-fuel-cell/25163/).  The basic idea is that plants produce organic compounds, which are broken down by soil microorganisms to produce carbon dioxide, electrons, and hydrogen ions.  Ordinarily the hydrogen ions and electrons combine with oxygen to form water, but there are various ways to divert the electrons to travel through an electrical circuit before the oxidation reaction takes place.  This flow of electrons (electricity) can be used as a power source.

This technology is still in its early stages but the process has been demonstrated in some laboratory proof-of-concepts:

- Strik, David P. B. T. B.; Hamelers (Bert), H. V. M.; Snel, Jan F. H.; Buisman, Cees J. N. (2008). "Green electricity production with living plants and bacteria in a fuel cell". *International Journal of Energy Research* **32**: 870–876. doi:[10.1002/er.1397](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/er.1397).
- De Schamphelaire, Liesje; Van den Bossche, Leen; Dang, Hai Son; Höfte, Monica; Boon, Nico; Rabaey, Korneel; Verstraete, Willy (2008). "Microbial fuel cells generating electricity from rhizodeposits of rice plants". *Environmental Science and Technology* **42** (8): 3053–3058. doi:[10.1021/es071938w](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/es071938w).

The E-Kaia company has not released enough information to say whether their product is in fact a plant microbial fuel cell, a simple [earth battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_battery), or a mere scam.

Comment: Can you cite the claim that the product is in fact a microbial fuel cell?

Comment: @MarchHo  Based on the company's [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/EnergiaAmigable), the product uses a "biocircuit" to "capture the residual energy of plants" (in other words, it runs on "[woo](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Woo)").  The Daily Mail article implies that the technology is similar to the [plant-e](http://plant-e.com/) technology, which is definitely a microbial fuel cell.  The other possibility is that the E-Kaia product is a simple [Earth battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_battery) and the plant plays no actual role in power generation.

Comment: @MarchHo I have revised my question to primarily address the larger question "Can electricity be harvested from the soil around plants?"